# How to do external API call in antd admin

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I am trying to do an external API call using the git project https://github.com/zuiidea/antd-admin. Even after trying for more that 2 weeks i couldn't able to figure it out. This package is using mock data which is giving the data feed for the sample pages. But i am going to use this package to build a separate web app for one of my project.

I tried to fetch one of the online json api from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ but i cant able to fetch the data. I still cant figure out where i need to call the api since it was using dva, umi framework

I need an example so that i can call the api from this package which will be helpful for me to complete my project.

Answer (score 0):

In .umirc.js file you must declare proxy for app like below

```
proxy: {
    '/api/v1/': {
      target: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: { '^/api/v1/': '' },
    },
},
```

After that you can test external API like this

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:<port>/api/v1/todos
```